# How do I go about placing an object in a #define statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, c-preprocessor

How do I go about placing an object in a #define statement like this:

```
#define PlacesURL @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=34.0522222,-118.2427778&radius=500&types=**bar**&sensor=false&key=MyAPIKey"
```

so, in place of **bar** I want to do something like %@ but am not sure how to store the %@ object. Also, where would I store the object - above the #define directive? I want to store bar, restaurants, coffee shops etc... for a Google Places Api search from an iOS app.

Comment: Couldnt you just use: [NSString stringWithFormat: PlacesURL, theTypeString]; if you replace bar with %@

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand, you have two options:

```
#define PLACES     @"bar,restaurants"
#define PlacesURL  ([NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=34.0522222,-118.2427778&radius=500&types=%@&sensor=false&key=MyAPIKey", PLACES])
```

or

```
#define PlacesURL( places ) ([NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=34.0522222,-118.2427778&radius=500&types=%@&sensor=false&key=MyAPIKey", places])
```

The second one is probably what you want, though both are a little pointless...

Answer (score 1):

you should following code:

```
#define PlacesURL(value) ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=34.0522222,-118.2427778&radius=500&types=%@&sensor=false&key=MyAPIKey", value])
```

> `#define` statement must have a the bracket. Let's look at the example below. You must return the expected result is 900, but 230 will
>   appear. This is just an example of one kind. You sure do not forget
>   the bracket. Beginning and end of the sentence in parentheses, as
>   well as the end of the each sentences must be in position.

```
#define A 10
#define B 20
#define C A+B
// not 900, result value is 230. 'Cause, proceed as follows: A+B*A+B
NSLog(@"value:%d", C*C);
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, any two constant strings listed together are considered one string, so any of the following are equivalent:

```
a = "abc123xyz";

b = "abc" "123" "xyz";

#define FOO "123"
c = "abc" FOO "xyz";
```

So, you can do what you want like this:

```
#define BAR "whatever"
#define PlacesURL "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=34.0522222,-118.2427778&radius=500&types=" BAR "&sensor=false&key=MyAPIKey"
```

But, that seems like a very strange thing to do? Are you trying to paste in the bar name at runtime? If so, you'd need to do it with sprintf (note the `%s` in the `PlacesURL`):

```
#define PlacesURL "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=34.0522222,-118.2427778&radius=500&types=%s&sensor=false&key=MyAPIKey"

char *get_url(char *bar) {
  char url[1000];

  sprintf (url, PlacesURL, bar);
  return strdup(url);
}
```

The calling function then has to `free(url)` when it's done with it.

Comment: Your #define Bar then #define PlacesURL won't work (as the OP expects) because it returns a C string not a NSString object. Dito for the second option.

Comment: @Paul de Lange: Adjacent iteral `NSString`s will be automatically concatenated just like C strings, so the first option can be converted.

Comment: +1 to @W'rkncacnter for teaching me something on this slow afternoon :)

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what language iOS uses, so I wrote "In C ...". I realised after I'd posted that there was an "objective-c" tag. I know that Objective-C is a superset of C, so I presume it will work, but, as you say, only with conversions.

Comment: @ams: Well, the only conversion necessary in this case is to add the `@` to the front of the string (and actually, it's only required on the _first_ string of the group): `@"Dost" "oyevsky"`